# Laravel 4 dynamic database filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4 to do a simple programming, I want to filter my database result using Laravel database fluent feature and I am stuck.

I have a filter the i need to pass to the select query:

```
$filter = Input::get( 'filter' );
$txtfilter = Input::get( 'txtfilter' );
$wh = '';
switch ($filter) {
        case 'hostname':
            $wh = "->where('hostname',$txtfilter)";
        case 'error':
            $wh = "->where('error',$txtfilter)";
        default:
            $wh = "";
}
```

Basically I want to add the above `$wh` to the below queries

```
$logs = DB::table('sys_logs')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    $wh
    ->paginate(200);
```

How do I do this?

tq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably that will do for the example you gave us:

```
$query = DB::table('sys_logs')->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');

$filter = Input::get( 'filter' );
$txtfilter = Input::get( 'txtfilter' );

if ($filter, in_array('hostname','error'))
{
    $query->where($filter, $txtFilter);
}

return $query->paginate(200);
```

But you can also do things like

```
foreach(Input::all() as $key => $value)
{
    $query->where($key, $value);    
}
```